# Changing sensor coordinate system in android

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, coordinate-systems

Android provides sensor data in device coordinate system no matter how it is oriented. Is there any way to have sensor data in 'gravity' coordinate system? I mean no matter how the device is oriented I want accelerometer data and orientation in coordinate system where y-axis points toward the sky, x-axis toward the east and z-axis towards south pole.

I took a look at `remapCoordinateSystem` but seems to be limited to only swapping axis. I guess for orientation I will have to do some low level rotation matrix transformation (or is there any better solution?). But how about acceleration data? Is there any way to have data in relation to coordinate system that is fixed (sort of world coordinate system).

The reason I need this is I'm trying to do some simple motion gestures when phone is in the pocket and it would be easier for me to have all data in coordinates system related to user rather device coordinate system (that will have a little bit different orientation in different user's pockets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you basically get the North orientation when starting - for this you use the accelerometer and the magnetic field sensor to compute orientation (or the deprecated Orientation sensor).

Once you have it you can compute a rotation matrix (Direction Cosine Matrix) from those azimuth, pitch and roll angles. Multiplying your acceleration vector by that matrix will transform your device-frame movements into Earth-frame ones.

As your device will change its orientation as time goes by, you'll need to update it. To do so, retrieve gyroscope's data and update your Direction Cosine Matrix for each new value. You could also get the orientation true value just like the first time, but it's less accurate.

My solution involves DCM, but you could also use quaternions, it's just a matter of choice. Feel free to ask more if needed. I hope this is what you wanted to know !